# not able show the image from mysql to php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am unable to show the image in PHP from MySQL blob showing a lot question marks.

below is my code.

```
if(isset($_GET['edituname']))
{
    $id='<input type="hidden" name="txtuname" value="' . $_GET['edituname'] . '">';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM andhra WHERE id='" . $_GET['edituname'] ."';";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $COL_1 = $row['COL_1'];
    $COL_2 = $row['COL_2'];
    $COL_8 = $row['COL_8'];
```

HTML code is

```
    <td><img src="data:images\jpg;base64,'.$COL_8.'" /></td>
```

my workarounds are

if we put `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` not able to display the URL just two rectangle boxes in left hand corner in browser.

if we change HTML code like below getting some unexpected error.

```
<td><img src="data:images\jpg;base64,'.($row['COL_8']).'" /></td>
```

Comment: one of the reasons no one recommends storing images in the database

Comment: so how we need to display images dynamically as per the query any other way

Comment: @HanumaiahT try with  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM andhra WHERE id=" . $_GET['edituname'] ;`

Comment: Praveen Kumar still same i changed as you suggested

Comment: `'<input type="hidden" name="txtuname" value="' . $_GET['edituname'] . '">'`-> not a good idea, XSS prone, `"SELECT * FROM andhra WHERE id='" . $_GET['edituname'] ."'"` -> not a good idea, SQL injection-prone. `mysql_*` functions -> not a good idea, functions removed as of PHPv7

Comment: Is COL_8 a Base64-encoded binary value? If not, you can't use it directly as a data URI.

Comment: store the files in the file system( hint in its name) and the filename\path in the database.

Comment: Dagon am newbie to this code is it possible to give any example am also looking for this type of solution only

Comment: @HanumaiahT [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Tieson "COL_8" is the mysql column name

Comment: @HanumaiahT Obviously. But what is the column *type*? You can't just dump binary data at a data URI and expect magic to happen.

Comment: Tieson its LongBlob type

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 $img = $row['COL_8'];
echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. $img .'"/></td>';
```

Comment: getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in E:\xampp\htdocs\db\finals\users.php on line 188 "

Comment: I modify my answer

Comment: after change also same

Comment: ' $img = $row['COL_8'];
echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. $img .'"/></td>';'

Comment: now able to open the URL but getting "echo '';: ��G��C��o�6"

Comment: $img = $row['COL_8']; echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode( $img) .'"/></td>';

you try that now

Comment: after change also same

Comment: nice.... giving me some negative point on my answer...........

Anyways, change your data type into LongBlob instead of Blob.. size matter.. this is what I am using so it useful. <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" alt="photo"> ..

Comment: Sorry BlueAries, am just saying the result not negative try to understand my data type is LongBlob